# How to convert ZonedDateTime to XMLGregorianCalendar in Java 7

Tags: java-8, java-7

My java 7 application consuming a service whcih is in Java 8 , i am receiving a date as string like

```
"2020-04-13T12:36:13Z"
```

which is actually a ZonedDateTime.
i need to convert this string to XMLGregorianCalendar and send to another service ?
Since my application is in java 7 i could not parse the string to ZonedDateTime . Is there any way i can do this conversion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy when you know how.

```
    String receivedDateTimeString = "2020-04-13T12:36:13Z";
    
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(receivedDateTimeString);
    
    System.out.println(xmlgc);
```

Output:

> 2020-04-13T12:36:13Z

`ZonedDateTime.toString()` sometimes produces ISO 8601 format (and sometimes an extended format with a zone ID that is not part of ISO 8601). In your case you have got pure ISO 8601. Dates and times in XML documents use a variant of ISO 8601, it’s close enough that we can consider them the same for our purpose here. So an `XMLGregorianCalendar` instance is created directly from the ISO 8601 string, and its `toString` method produces the same ISO 8601 string back.

### ThreeTen Backport allows you to use ZonedDateTime in Java 7

You can, and you may prefer to use `ZonedDateTime` in Java 7 too rather than `XMLGregorianCalendar`. This use goes through ThreeTen Backport, the backport of java.time to Java 6 and 7, see the links at the bottom.

```
import org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime;

public class DemoZonedDateTimeInJava7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String receivedDateTimeString = "2020-04-13T12:36:13Z";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(receivedDateTimeString);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }

}
```

> 2020-04-13T12:36:13Z

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)